# Synchronize operation failed

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

When I try to sync with svn using eclipse, I get the error:

```
Synchronize operation failed.
svn: The path 'C:\abc\src\com\MyUtil.java' appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater
working copy rooted at 'C:\abc.
Please upgrade your Subversion (SVNKit) client to use this working copy.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your working copy has meta-data format (1.7) that your actual SVNKit cannot read.

Apparently you have checked out the working copy outside from eclipse with a newer version of an svn client.

The error mesage says it all, to resolv your problmem you could try to update the subversion plug-in of your eclipse. You can find the update site for the version you need in [this page](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA).

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have tried to check out outside eclipse.

I've encountered the same problem in past and I deleted the working copy and check out again inside eclipse.

The working copy is a .svn hidden folder.